# Is it possible to inspect post parameters of network request in Android Profiler

Tags: android

Is it possible to inspect POST parameters of a request?
E.g. my URL is https://[myrestapi].com/get_puppy_by_name.php and my parameter is "puppyname=rantanplan".

Android Studio Profiler shows me:

- the request
- the method
- the status
- the content type
- the size
- the URL

and the Response including headers. Also the Call Stack is shown.
But there is no trace of my POST parameters.
This would be a really convenient feature, if it is not possible yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This feature is available since Android Studio 3.1 Canary 5. See [this announcement](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/12/android-studio-31-canary-5-is-now.html).